# Using uuid.uuid4() as default value

Tags: python, django

I want to make model like

```
import uuid
class UserData(models.Model):
    id_key = # give uuid.uuid4() as default value
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default=timezone.now)
```

When `UserData` is made in script, `id_key` value should be made automatically.

```
ud = UserData()
ud.save()
```

I guess I should make a function as default value though, I am not clear yet.

how can I make this??

Comment: What about [**`UUIDField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)

Comment: That's what I want. Thank you verymuch and super useful than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has built-in uuid field:

```
import uuid

class UserData(models.Model):
     id_key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
     ... your other stuff ...
```